# How to split the date based on check-In and check-out date in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a hotel system need to split the date( duration of stay), The start date( Check-In) and EndDate(check-out) are selected by user in datepicker. like this:

```html
<div class="datebox">
    <input type="text" show-button-bar='false' class="form-control biginput" datepicker-popup ng-model="lodging.checkIn" is-open="checkin" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
    <span class="dateicon" style='right:5px;' ng-click="openCheckIn($event)"></span> 
</div>
<div class="datebox">
    <input type="text" show-button-bar='false'
        class="form-control biginput" datepicker-popup
        ng-model="Lodging.checkOut" is-open="checkout" min-date='lodging.checkIn'
        datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true"
        close-text="Close" />
    <span class="dateicon" style='right:5px;' ng-click="openCheckOut($event)"></span>
</div>
```

Users will choose check-in and check-out days from above two datepicker. I need to split out the information for each stays, such that if I choose check-in : 11/01/2015 check-out: 11/05/2015, I need to create a table to show each stay's expense from date 11/01/2015 to 11/05/2015. It will be like following table:

```
Date           Amount
11/01/2015     109
11/02/2015     120
11/03/2015     101
11/04/2015     99
```

How to split out the duration date (like the first columnn of the table)and put them in the ng-repeat for my table?

Comment: Start a loop at first date and increment by one day until you get to end date. What have you tried? Library like moment.js can be helpful for things like this but also not difficult using javascript Date object

Comment: @linyuanxie - can you show me the checkin checkout datepicker code of angularjs, here I require the same functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prepare your table with ng-repeat

```
<table ng-init="loadStays()" ng-if="stays">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="stay in stays | between:lodging.checkIn:lodging.checkOut">
      <td>{{ stay.date | date : 'mm-dd-yyyy' }}</td>
      <td>{{ stay.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, create a filter for display only items between date from and date to (if I understand your question correctly)

```
// For parse a date in format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
// If you have to parse the date from your item (maybe datetime ?)
// Use the built-in date filter
// like date = $filter('date')(item.date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
parseDate = function(input) {
    var parts = input.split('-');
    return new Date(parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[0]);
};

// Create the filter assuming app is your module.
app.filter('between', function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {
      filtered = [];
      var dateFrom = parseDate(from);
      var dateTo = parseDate(to);
      if (from == '' && to == '')
          return items;
      filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
        if (from !== '' && to == '') {
          return item.date >= dateFrom;
        } else if (from == '' && to !== '') {
            return item.date <= dateFrom;
        } else if (from !== '' && to !== '') {
            return item.date >= dateFrom && item.date <= dateTo
        }
      });

      return filtered;
  };
});
```

With this code, stays are dynamically filtered and user see only items with a `date` attribute between your lodging.checkIn and logding.checkOut dates taken from datepicker ng-models.

And in case of you don't know how retrieve stays from your server, use something like :

```
// Retrieve stays from yourdomain/stays
$scope.loadStays = function() {
    $http.get('stays').then(function(response) {
        $scope.stays = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```